# How to redirect to https index.html with .htacess

Tags: vue.js, .htaccess, single-page-application, vue-cli

I have a vue-laravel spa. For the vue app to work properly with the history mode, I need to make sure that it redirects to index.html. I am following what the vue cli documentation says for that and use this piece of code in the .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

At the same time I also need to make sure that all http request are redirected to https for which my hostgator hosting provided me with this piece of code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/subdomain\.domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

The problem is that these 2 pieces of code don't seem to work together. Each of them work when the other is commented out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order is important. The canonical (HTTP to HTTPS) redirect needs to go *before* the rewrites to `index.html`.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain\.com$
> RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/subdomain\.domain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
> ```

However, this rule as written redirects to itself and would result in a redirect-loop! (This isn't part of the HTTP to HTTPS redirect.)

You do not need the `<IfModule>` wrapper and you do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive.

In other words:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Front-Controller
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

You're not actually using the `RewriteBase` directive, so I removed it.

Comment: I tried this but when a URL was reloaded it returned a TOO MANY REDIRECTS error